# How do you find the link for an answer

Tags: support, hyperlinks, answers

I am trying to give a link to an answer generated by Daniel Lichtblau. However, looking at his page he has so many answers that I could not find it and there is no search box to help. I know the name of the question he answered and I can even find the answer. However, I want the link to go to the answer Daniel gave and not the question that was asked.

Comment: Hover over his name anywhere or look at the URL of his profile page to see his user ID, and then use the normal search box with `user: <id here>` appended. This will limit the search to only posts that are his.

Comment: In the lower left corner of the post (question or answer) there are some grey links: share, edit, flag. "Share" will give you the link you want.

Comment: @OleksandrR. thanks. Your method works fine.